# Storing variable-value combination in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Im  complete beginner to R, coming mostly from python. Im trying to have a dataframe that stores variable-value pair in order to transform it further to json file. However, when I create empty frame and add variables via function, it shows that it is still empty.

The code I currently use:

```
df <- data.frame(custom_var=character(), 
                 custom_val=character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

store_variable <- function(myvar, myval) {
  new.row <- data.frame(custom_var=myvar, custom_val=myval, stringsAsFactors = F)
  df <- rbind(df, new.row)
}

store_variable("asd", 4)
store_variable("parent", "texas")
print(df)
```

Prints out

```
print(df)
[1] custom_var custom_val
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Ive also used an approach with df[nrow(df) + 1,] = list(variable, value) found from other tutorials but it still doesnt store anything in df

What is the issue here? Are there more elegant ways of storing those? As a result I need a json file with unique key:value pair.

Comment: Use double arrow at this step like: `df <<- rbind(df, new.row)`

Comment: Wow it actually did the trick! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a problem with global/local variables and therefore the dataframe you use inside the function is not recognized as being the same as the the dataframe you created outside of the function.

You can use this code instead of your function:

```
df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c(value1, value2, ...)

df <- data.frame(custom_var=character(), 
                 custom_val=character(),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("asd", 4)
df[nrow(df) + 1,] = c("parent", "texas")

print(df)

  custom_var custom_val
1        asd          4
2     parent      texas
```

Comment: I also assume its the scoping issue, but have no idea how to overcome this. Your solution did not work, also as I remember c(val1, val2) may not work properly with mixed types